Italian input language with US alt. intl. keyboard layout?
I'm Italian and oftentimes I have to write emails, documents and texts in Italian, but for my day-to-day computing and programming tasks I prefer to use the US keyboard layout and I have a couple of US-layout keyboards. Also, I find writing combinations like "È" actually quicker on an US alt. intl. keyboard layout.
I would like to set the language to Italian on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS but use the US, alt. intl. keyboard layout as input. The Italian (US) keyboard layout doesn't appear to account for accents, phonetic symbols and other stuff like that. I don' t see the Italian (US, alt. intl.) option.
Am I missing something? How do I set that layout up?
Thank you very much!

The easiest way to do this is to install both keyboards. The one that is first (on top) will be the default.
Then you can put a keyboard selector in the main panel.
There is another more practical solution which is to modify the keyboard layout and assign the unused "alt-key" combinations to the characters you need. The bad news is that this will take some effort.
Using the same keyboard you use (US International) I added the characters needed to type the Esperanto letters. If you don't know how to do it, I can tell you.
That could help you: How to remap keys with xmodmap
More info: xmodmap is a utility for modifying keymaps
